# External database association in Rails . Update data

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have the following problem:

I have two models , that are connected to an external database (Mysql)
The right name of the two tables in the external database are:
`f_aziende` and `f_partecipanti` (it's italian).
In my Rails app i created two models to connect to these tables and i called:

`formation_db` and `reference_db`.

Here my models code:

```
class ReferenceDb < ActiveRecord::Base
        establish_connection "#{Rails.env}_db2"
        self.table_name = "f_partecipanti"
    self.primary_key = 'id'


        belongs_to :formation_db 

end

class FormationDb < ActiveRecord::Base
        establish_connection "#{Rails.env}_db2"
        self.table_name = "f_aziende"
    self.primary_key = 'id'


        has_many :reference_dbs , :foreign_key => "id_azienda"

end
```

The problem is that i'm not able to update all the rows associated to `formation_db`. Also , i'm not sure if the association of the two models is correct. I mean , in this case what is the convenction of the rails words?

In my others project i usually write:

```
@company.update_attributes(params[:company])
```

and i update all the things related to company in one line of code.
How can i create something similar to this in my case?

Comment: Can you paste error ?

Comment: it's not an error. it's something that i dont  have idea how to program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're walking perilously close to the line of "multi tenancy", which is why you're running into difficulty I think.

Anyway, [I found there's a way](http://ilikestuffblog.com/2012/09/21/establishing-a-connection-to-a-non-default-database-in-rails-3-2-2/) to connect to other DBs without having to redclare it in each model:

```
#app/vendor/db.rb
class Db < ActiveRecord::Base
    establish_connection "#{Rails.env}_db2"
end

#app/models/reference_db.rb
class ReferenceDb < Db
   self.table_name = "f_partecipanti"
   belongs_to :formation_db 
end

#app/models/formation_db.rb
class FormationDb < Db
   self.table_name = "f_aziende"
   has_many :reference_dbs , :foreign_key => "id_azienda"
end
```

This will at least set up your models succinctly.

--

These models will work like any other one in Rails. The only caveat is that you cannot join across different databases; IE you cannot have a `has_many :through` with the databases aforementioned.

```
@company = Company.find params[:id]
@company.update_all ....
```

Comment: Hey Richard, I am actually struggling with te connection two models which uses different databases with `has_many through`. [Please, take a look](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36151369/migration-using-external-database) - may be you could advice.. Many thanks!